# Linear program geometry

Tags: geometry, linear-programming, polyhedra, constraints

I’ve tried to solve a question in my homework, and I don’t really know what to do.
In the problem a polyhedron is given and I need to build the set of constraints that defines this polyhedron.

[image: polyhedron]

The faces of the Polyhedron are BCD, BCEO, BDFO, CDFE, EFO.

I never done that or seen an example. I have a "guess", I know that it's 3 dimension so it's probably a linear combination of three vectors, $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ $(x,y,z)$, with other constraints.

\begin{align*}
x_1+x_2+x_3&\leq3,\\
x_1&\leq1,\\
x_2&\leq2,\\
x_1,x_2,x_3&\geq0.
\end{align*}

Am I right?

After that I need to find the set of vectors C that the face CDFE is the set of optimal solutions for the max problem define by this Polyhedron.

What exactly I need to do in the second part?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE! I edited your post a little to make it clearer to read. If I made any mistakes, feel free to correct them. Also--is there a number next to the point E? If not, I'm not sure there's actually enough information to answer this question uniquely.

Comment: Regarding part 2, you need to find the vector normal to the face $CDFE$. If it’s not clear why, try drawing some polyhedra in 2D and see if it becomes more apparent.

Answer (score 1):

Every plane, with equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$, divides all space into two parts (half-spaces) defined by $ax+by+cz+d>0$ and $ax+by+cz+d<0$. Your polyhedron is the intersection of five half-spaces, originating from its five faces.

For instance: faces $BCEO$ and $BDFO$ give two half spaces: $y>0$ and $x>0$. Proceed in the same way to find the other three constraints.

Comment: It looks to me like the point $E$ can slide up and down the $x$ axis, giving different facet-defining inequalities for  $EFA$. Can you make it out?

Comment: @DavidM. Isn't $E=(1,0,0)$?

Comment: Oh is that a $1$? Couldn’t tell!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took me so much time to respond, I was working on another question.
I thought about this question again. If we look we have two polyhedrons, AEOF and BGOH, and the polyhedron we need is the intersection between this two polyhedron. So I think this two equations describes our polyhedron:

4X+2Y+Z <= 4 and
X+2Y+2Z <= 6

what do you think?

Comment: You should have commented below my answer, instead of writing down an answer (?) which I didn't notice. Please delete it. Anyway, if you are still interested, the same question has been answered in detail [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4501771/255730).